# Can't get into recovery mode - Macbook Pro Mid 2014

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup, ssd, recovery

Yesterday I encountered serious problem with my Macbook. Morning I've been able to work on him like everyday, then I closed the lid to do some other stuff. When I opened it back, it was turned off.

In this point I have to admit that I encountered that before, but restarting one or couple times always solved thing. Well, now it didn't. Everytime I could see only **question mark folder**.

So far here's what I did after that:

- Standard procedure of resetting SMC and PRAM/NVRAM
- Holding power key for longer time
- Finally booting up in recovery mode (`Command + R`)

And to be honest real problem starts now.

I booted up to Mavericks recovery (which is default for my Mid 2014), but I wasn't able to see my disk during reinstallation of MacOS. I went to disk utility then I noticed only "disk0" with description of "Base OS X System".

Well, first thought - SSD is dead BUT... I'm using adapter connected to my Macbook and **NVME M.2 SSD attached to adapter**. I found on internet that Mavericks disk utility is not able to see this kind of drive, so next thought - **let's try newest disk utility via internet recovery**.

Instead of hitting `Command + R` I tried `Command + Alt/Option + R`. It is important to let you know, that I used internet recovery successfully, when I installed lastest OS on my Macbook (a year ago). However in this point recovery failed to boot (after providing WiFi and waiting couple of minutes) with error -0000F < it's not code of error, but everytime I try to use recovery I receive different numbers. For now it's -2005F with triangle and exclamation mark on globe.

Well, then I hitted another SMC + PRAM/NVRAM clear and tried again. Same error. Things gets spicy, because **now I can't even access internal recovery** (`Command + R`).

Summary in current point:

- I'm not able to access any recovery (always get some error).
- I'm not able to boot up Macbook (gets black screen or after clearing PRAM/NVRAM - again question mark folder)

What I tried to do after those steps:

- Connect WiFi from drive menu, where I also didn't noticed any disk (holding `Alt/Option` after chime sound)
- Couple of SMC and PRAM/NVRAM clears
- Holding power button for so long.
- Trying steps with connected and disconnected MagSafe.
- Clearing adapter and SSD from dust.

What are possibilities in my opinion:

- SSD or apdater is dead (or both), but I can't check it - I don't have other suitable device.
- Everything with hardware is fine, but Mavericks just wasn't able to see my disk (I wish)
- More deep problem. (Unfortunately most probable)

So... Any ideas? I can try to create bootable USB from Windows machine, but I don't know if it is even worth. Everything looks fine with my Macbook from hardware side (apart from adapter/SSD).

Thank you to everyone who even read this.

Comment: I would have assumed it has a drive/ adapter issue based on the question mark icon.  Have you tried different ports on the MacBook to connect the adapter to?  I would try and find a different machine to check it can actually be seen if you can ask a friend or someone before you take more drastic action.  Also have you tried using Option-Shift-Command-R to start up?  That tries to install the version that came with your machine or the latest supported version available in case what you tried is attempting an unsupported version? https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl338cf9a8/mac

Comment: I don't have another ports in my MacBook. I only have one NGFF socket inside Mac. I will take my SSD to friend and check if it is working properly, then come back :).

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood when you said "I'm using adapter connected to my Macbook and NVME M.2 SSD attached to adapter". I thought you meant you had tried connecting an adapter and ssd externally.

Comment: It's something like Sintech NGFF M.2 NVMe, but cheaper one. Tommorow I'll check out, hope it's only adapter, not SSD :)

Anyway is there any possibility that it's not problem with either adapter or SSD, but something wrong with motherboard?

Comment: The SSD is working just fine, so i guess it's adapter fault.

Answer (score -1):

Problem was the adapter. Unfortunately I've obtained cheaper one when buying Macbook.

There's photo of it:
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).